# Glue - A result set was generated for update error

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm inserting simple dataframe with Glue to RDS Sql Server instance.

Last row (of 8 in total) doesn't get inserted and throws error:

```
FAILED: table_name, Exception: An error occurred while calling o216.pyWriteDynamicFrame. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: 

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 15 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 15.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 35, 10.234.42.138, executor 1): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: A result set was generated for update.
```

I checked the structure of the table, constraints, indexes, triggers between failing environment (dev) and remaining ones and did not find any differences. Also I'm excluding issues with Glue/Python as my `function.py` in the job is used in all environments.

From SQ: Server profiler I can confirm that insert is being retried 4 times and got additional logs:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 bigint,N'INSERT INTO [schema].[table] ("col","col","col") VALUES (@P0,@P1,@P2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ',N'xyz',N'xyz',7,N'xyz'
select @p1


exec sp_unprepare 1

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Thanks for suggestions on where to go further with this...

Comment: The SQL in your question is malformed. Are you sure that's what's being passed?

Comment: Probably typo while copying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being below workaround did the job:

1. Disable triggers on the table
2. Truncate the table
3. Re-run Glue job, data gets popullated
4. Enable triggers
5. Re-run Glue job again, data gets now updated